# Mozilla C/C++ coding style

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, boolean, language-lawyer

Today I was going through the ["Mozilla Coding Style Guideline"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Coding_Style#C.2FC.2B.2B_practices) and I found a point I am not sure about.

What do they mean with the following statement?

> Do not compare `x == true` or `x == false`. Use `(x)` or `(!x)` instead. `x == true`, in fact, is different from `if (x)`!

I am not sure how these two methods are different. Please clarify.

Comment: Does it really say "**C/C++** coding style"? I would see that as a big red flag. For instance, `true` and `false` are not the same in both languages.

Comment: Why don't you email them and ask them?

Comment: @juanchopanza They [do](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Coding_Style).

Comment: @DanielDaranas That's disappointing (although these are the least offensive C++ coding guidelines I've seen, probably due to their brevity.) I may send them a comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Evaluation of `x == true` and/or `x == false` depends on the definitions of `true` and `false`, which may *not* be universally the same.

`(x)` and `(!x)` are evaluated based on the value of `x` only and does not depend on any platform / implementation / standard specific definitions. For example, `(x)` will be evaluated to produce a *TRUE* result in case of `x` having a *non-zero* value.

In `C`, as per `C11` standard, `stdbool.h` header, chapter `7.18` the definition of `true` and `false` are

> **true**
>
> which expands to the integer constant 1,
>
> **false**
>
> which expands to the integer constant 0

so, in case of `x` having a value `2`

- `x == true` will be evaluated to produce *FALSE*.
- `(x)` will produce *TRUE*.

So, to produce a robust code and maintain portability, it's better to use the later approach.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ false is `0` and anything else is true, but when you compare `x == true` you are actually testing weather `x == 1` which is OK in some cases but not all.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages, even in that aspect.

Comment: I believe you are wrong. Consider `x` being an instance of a `class` providing some *explicit* `operator bool` conversion.

Comment: Also, `false` is not `0` in C++. It may convert to `0` is some situations, but it isn't `0`.

Answer (score 0):

C and  C++ are different languages.

In C99 or C11, everything can be used as a test, with the conventions:

1. A `bool` (from `<stdbool.h>`) value which is `false` is tested as false, otherwise it should be `true` and tested as true.
2. An integer type (e.g. `int`, `long`, `intptr_t` from `<stdint.h>`, etc...) is tested as false only if it is 0
3. A floating point type (e.g. `double`) is tested false if it is 0.0, as true if it is a non-zero number For `NAN` it is a specific issue. See [Floating point guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/)
4. A pointer type is tested false if it `NULL` and otherwise is tested true. I forgot what the standard says about invalid pointers (not the result of unary address-of `&` operator or of `malloc` etc...)

In C++11, you can have explicit conversion to `bool` with `operator bool` and explicit unary `!` operator with `operator !` so things are much more complex. I believe (but I am not sure) that `x == true` would use the conversion to `bool` operator on `x`, at least if that operator is explicit.

I am sure that there are subtle corner cases (in C, a pointer to some *existing* function is true, but I forgot what the standard says about a pointer to function in general...). In C++, it is a nightmare.

Comment: Evaluating an invalid pointer is undefined, no matter where it's done, also in an `if` expression (if the code is reached).